# Dynamically filter for multiple tags in org agenda

Tags: org-agenda, org-tags, org-super-agenda

As far as I can see there are no previous questions on here that address my specific need, despite some being fairly similar.
In the agenda view, I can use `org-agenda-filter-by-tag` to filter for/against certain tags. However the prompt that appears only allows me to search for one tag at a time, and the org match syntax that would allow me to filter for multiple tags does not seem to be supported in this context (i.e. "`work|laptop`" is not a valid search term). To be clear, one can accumulate tag filters in this way, but this does not provide the "OR" functionality I'm looking for.
I'm aware that I can use `org-tags-view` to allow me to perform this type of search as it suports the org match syntax, however I have a custom agenda view set up with `org-super-agenda` and do not want to lose the groupings I have, nor do I want to set these groupings globally. I really do just want to filter this custom agenda view for multiple tags.
I'm also aware that I can create custom agenda views for each of the search terms I would like to perform, however there are many different combinations of tags I would like to filter for/against, and which combinations I need to filter for cannot always be anticipated, hence the need for this to  be dynamic.
Maybe I'm missing an obvious trick here, I would appreciate any help that can be provided.
Thanks

Comment: Yup. Using helm, the input syntax documented here, https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html, doesn't work. eg +xx|+yy.

Comment: Are there any ways around this?

Comment: I can only suggest to raise an "issue".

Comment: If I do `\ <TAB> foo RET C-u C-u \ <TAB> bar RET` in the agenda, I get items tagged  `foo` OR `bar`. Why is that not good enough? What else are you looking for?

Comment: That would be good enough! But it doesn't seem to work for me. Can you confirm that the above definitely does the trick on your end?